# Can I ask people to test a program?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, testing

I've just finished working with a **huge** program for demonstrating a routing algorithm (using `LinkedList`s in Java). And although it seems to be working fine, I would like for more people to look it over to make sure there are no bugs. Can I ask people to test my program on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It'd have to be a rather trivial program to have any confidence that it has *no* bugs.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see that as a real question as such. I'd be loathe for SO to become a beta test advertising site. If you're talking about people performing a code review, I suspect few people really want to review hundreds of lines of code. Individual routines are likely to get more useful feedback - or general design questions. You can try, but don't be surprised if you don't get much out of it.

Comment: could you possibly suggest where i can get people to test it? (if not on SO)

Comment: is there a comp.lang.java type forum/newsgroup that *might* accept this type of invite? Otherwise I'm not sure of the price, but http://www.uTest.com/ provides online testers from around the globe to help test an application.

Comment: It's still not clear whether you want actual beta testers to run the app - in which case, it will very much depend on what the app is - or people to review your code.

Comment: Or write unit tests. :)

Answer (score 6):

You will have a hard time convincing those looking at your question to trust you to run the code (especially if you are an unknown user).

Just as it is generally not a good idea to open up attachments in an email from people you don't know, running code which you are unsure of the source could be just as dangerous.

Comment: Or in this case, **a lot** more dangerous.

Comment: If it's packaged as an (unsigned!) applet or WebStart/JNLP application it should be reasonably safe.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow works best for discrete, specific questions. I have seen a few *fairly small* "please review this" questions, but they are rare.

Comment: Most questions I see which say 'review my code' get very poor feedback. I don't know how many people actually wants to read through hundreds of lines of someone else's code because A) you have to first understand what it does, and B) It applies to no one other than the OP.

Answer (score 1):

you can ask, but the question would probably be closed quite rapidly ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Questions like these can now go to [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). It opened about a year and a half after this question was asked, and it's been in beta for about that long, too. Please do not ask questions like this on Stack Overflow.

Also, for people who arrive here looking for beta testers: Stack Exchange is trying to set up a beta testing service. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102582/were-ready-to-beta-test-our-beta-tester-matchmaking-program for more information.

Answer (score -1):

*Can* you ask? Yes. I can't guarantee the response, but I doubt it will be what you're looking for.