# Can I ask people to improve my program?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I wrote a program that lets you assign stat points to five different stats. However, it uses some fairly complex if–else statements, six different goto statements, and a ton of string variables.

I would like someone to take a look at it, and try to improve it, but I am not sure if
"Please improve my program" is an appropriate question to ask on the non-meta Stack Overflow site.

Comment: Delete this question and put it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JeremyThompson I will check it out, thanks!

Comment: @JeremyThompson Delete? Why??

Answer (score 4):

As Jeremy Thompson recommended, try asking on Code Review.

From their about page:

> Code Review is a question and answer site for **sharing code from projects you are working on for peer review**. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed code reviews.

*Emphasis added*

*However* I don't think you should delete this question as it might still be useful to others that see it.

Comment: @EliahKagan +1 I agree on the basis there are no duplicates to this question and some people may not know about the beta. A similar question was asked over 3 years ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4567/can-i-ask-people-to-test-a-program